# Is it possible to change the Vim background color after a certain line in the file (`private` in a Ruby class definition)?

Tags: vim

I would love to be able to see in Vim whether I'm in the "private" section of a Ruby class definition or not. Class definitions look like this:

```
class Foo
  def a_public_method
  end

  private

  def a_private_method
  end
end
```

Would it be possible to get Vim to change the background color of the `private` line and everything after?

Comment: You may take a look at this [post](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/syntax-highlight-for-whole-line)

Comment: Thank you @mbjoe. Will look into "signs". I should point out that I want to highlight not just that line, but also every line after. An alternative solution I'm considering is a command like `:IsThisLinePrivate` to tell me, instead of relying on colour.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is:

```
:call matchadd('Error', '^.*private\_.\{-}\(^end\)\@=')
```

assuming the `end` closing `class` starts always at the beginning of a line (not a very elegant solution).
You can use another highlight group listed by `:hi` instead of `'Error'`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm afraid that this doesn't seem to work if the `private` line is offscreen. My main use case is that I'm inside a long class and the `private` line is offscreen, so I don't know if I'm above or below it.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42704931/can-vim-matchadd-work-if-matched-lines-are-off-screen/45080692

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to mark private methods in ruby for years, but I always start and stop, and, now, I finally have a reasonably-working idea, thanks to your question. So, thanks for that.

Now, first off, the *ideal* solution would use Vim's built-in highlighting to extend ruby's syntax file. The way I'd imagine this would work is by defining a syntax region (`:help syn-region`) that starts with a "private" and ends with an "end". The tricky bit is that the "private" needs to have been marked with a particular syntax group, `rubyAccess`, or it might just be any "private" in a string, or comment. And the `end` needs to be `rubyClass`, or it might be closing not a class, but a method's `def` or a `do`.

Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to pull this off. I can't find a way to define a syntax region from a particular group to another one. If you want to study syntax highlighting, and maybe someday come up with a solution to the problem, here's ruby's syntax highlighting: https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/blob/f792ee3b2d005660da2e7303e43721ef222d7047/syntax/ruby.vim

Now, that said, after I defined the problem in the terms above, I realized I *could* just find the relevant "private" and "end" keywords, with the right syntax groups, upon saving the buffer or something. Considering you're thinking of an explicit command anyway, this might be a feasible solution to you as well.

I have a gist here, if you find that more readable: https://gist.github.com/AndrewRadev/d848ad9621b47b4151bbc61ab6c5765f. It needs to go in `~/.vim/ftplugin/ruby.vim`. Here it is, annotated with some comments:

```
" Define what color the private area will be
hi rubyPrivateArea ctermbg=darkgray

function! s:MarkPrivateArea()
  " Clear out any previous matches
  call clearmatches()

  " Store the current view, in order to restore it later
  let saved_view = winsaveview()

  " start at the last char in the file and wrap for the
  " first search to find match at start of file
  normal! G$
  let flags = "w"
  while search('\<private\>', flags) > 0
    let flags = "W"

    if s:CurrentSyntaxName() !~# "rubyAccess"
      " it's not a real access modifier, keep going
      continue
    endif

    let start_line = line('.')

    " look for the matching "end"
    let saved_position = getpos('.')
    while search('\<end\>', 'W') > 0
      if s:CurrentSyntaxName() !~# "rubyClass"
        " it's not an end that closes a class, keep going
        continue
      endif

      let end_line = line('.') - 1
      call matchadd('rubyPrivateArea', '\%'.start_line.'l\_.*\%'.end_line.'l')
      break
    endwhile

    " restore where we were before we started looking for the "end"
    call setpos('.', saved_position)
  endwhile

  " We're done highlighting, restore the view to what it was
  call winrestview(saved_view)
endfunction

function! s:CurrentSyntaxName()
  return synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 0), "name")
endfunction

augroup rubyPrivateArea
  autocmd!

  " Initial marking
  autocmd BufEnter <buffer> call <SID>MarkPrivateArea()

  " Mark upon writing
  autocmd BufWrite <buffer> call <SID>MarkPrivateArea()

  " Mark when not moving the cursor for 'timeoutlen' time
  autocmd CursorHold <buffer> call <SID>MarkPrivateArea()
augroup END
```

At a high level: It defines a function, `s:MarkPrivateArea` that performs the actual searching and marking of the area. The `s:` indicates it's script-local, so it doesn't pollute the global namespace. It's later called in autocommands as `<SID>MarkPrivateArea` -- it's the same function.

The function starts from the end of the file, loops around, and then forbids looping, letting it cover the entirety of the file, only once. It looks for "private" with the right syntax group, finds the very next "end" that closes a class, and saves the `start_line` and `end_line` for that region. You can play around with adding or removing `- 1` in order to decide if your "region" should include or exclude the "private" and whether it should include or exclude the final "end".

(Side note: for this to work, you need to have "expensive" syntax highlighting, but that should be on by default. Relevant docs: https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/blob/f792ee3b2d005660da2e7303e43721ef222d7047/doc/ft-ruby-syntax.txt#L71)

In the end, the start and end lines are combined into a pattern that looks like this:

```
'\%<start-line>l\_.*\%<end-line>.'l'
```

Try `:help \%l` for more info, but that's basically a regex pattern that matches code in a particular line of the file. And `\_.` is the multiline form of `.`. So, it matches everything from the start line to the end line.

If you wanted to change that so that only the `def`s got highlighted, it would look like this:

```
call matchadd('rubyPrivateArea', '\%>'.start_line.'l\<def\>\%<'.end_line.'l')
```

That's what I'll be doing, at least, but you did say you wanted the entire area marked.

The autocommands at the end run the function on startup, upon writing the file, and upon holding the cursor for some time. You could remove some of these, if you like. For instance, you might be okay even without the `CursorHold` one, if you save often.

As for the `rubyPrivateArea` highlight group at the top of the file, there's a full explanation on how you can set its colors with `:help highlight-args`. You could also take a look at your favorite colorscheme for some examples.

Comment: Wow, this is super ambitious. Thank you so much! Sadly it doesn't seem to highlight anything if the `private` line is offscreen (e.g. you've scrolled past it and everything you see is inside the private section), which is my core use case. Perhaps this is a limitation of `matchadd` – if so, your code is still a great basis for writing a "tell me if I'm in the private block" command that does not rely on syntax highlighting.

Comment: Wrote another question about the offscreen thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42704931/can-vim-matchadd-work-if-matched-lines-are-off-screen

Comment: Interesting. I had a similar issue with lack of offscreen highlighting in a different piece of Vimscript. My theory is that single matches are limited in size or something, so `\_.*` matches too much. Try removing the underscore and just matching `\.*`, this should match each line separately, instead of trying to contain the entire area. I might experiment a bit as well.

Comment: Seems like I can't reproduce your issue. I did have a similar one in a different situation, but it doesn't happen here. If you replace `\_.*` with `.*`, you might get a different result, but can't really test it out on my setup.