# Can Vim matchadd work if matched lines are off screen?

Tags: vim

If I run [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42372807/6962), meant to highlight everything from a `private` line to an `end` line:

```
:call matchadd('Error', '^.*private\_.\{-}\(^end\)\@=')
```

Then it only works if the `private` line is on screen.

If I scroll past it, so it's off screen, nothing is highlighted when I run that command.

Is that an inherent limitation of `matchadd`? Is there any way around it?

Comment: There's a problem somewhere else in your config because that command works perfectly. Try with `$ vim -Nu NONE +hi\ Error\ ctermbg=red`.

Comment: @romainl Thank you. I can still reproduce the issue if I start Vim like that. To be clear, I see the issue if I *first* scroll past "private" so it's offscreen, and *then* run the `:call …` command. Nothing is then highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:match` is meant for highlighting (short) stuff currently visible in a window. Therefore, for performance reasons, it limits the search scope to the currently visible text.

What you attempt to do is a misuse of the feature. If you really want this, determine the lines covering private functions on `:autocmd TextChanged,TextChangedI <buffer>`, and invoke `matchadd()` with a regular expression that matches all those line numbers (e.g. `\%>4l\%<7l.*`).

Comment: That's clever, thank you! I experimented a little just now and it seems like this would work.